# Alphanet problem - activating account with faucet

Tags: alphanet, docker, faucet

I'm running Alphanet on a Mac OSX and have everything running fine, but have hit a roadblock trying to activate an account with a faucet JSON. Totally new to Tezos.

I run the command:

```
./alphanet.sh client activate account myfaucet with "container:tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json"
```

Then I regularly get this error message:

```
Error:
Erroneous command line argument 5 (file:/tmp/tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json).
File doesn't exist: 'file:/tmp/tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json'
```

When I run the ./alphanet.sh shell and look in the file directory there, I can see the file in /tmp.

I've also tried specifying the path to the file on my system - e.g.

```
./alphanet.sh client activate account myfaucet with "container:/Users/myusername/Development/Tezos/tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json"
```

I get the same error as above. I don't know if Docker cannot attach the file to its image or I'm missing a parameter somewhere in my setup.

The node is fully bootstrapped, I've created a wallet without tezzies, and everything seems to run normally. However, I just cannot add tezzies via a faucet.

I've looked all around the internet and see the problem appear in a few places, but no real solutions. Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Docker's [cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command as a workaround.

In your case it would be something like:

```
docker cp tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json alphanet_node_1:/home/tezos/tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json
./alphanet.sh client activate account myfaucet with tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json
```

Comment: Thank you! That ended up working with one additional move. I needed to put the file into the /home/tezos directory of the docker container. So the original command can be "docker cp tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json alphanet_node_1:/home/tezos/tz1Zvjxu9Vzt76uRLtV6CHZMPu1zKA5YV4QX.json"

Comment: The other issue I was facing I noticed was that the client was not fully bootstrapped. I originally ran the command "$./alphanet client bootstrapped" and it ended stating that it was "bootstrapped". However, when looking at the time stamps, it timed out early. I needed to restart the node multiple times and re-run bootstrapped to get the client fully bootstrapped. Operations cannot be injected until the time stamp is current.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the answer according to your comment.